# How do I create a chart in Google Script and save it to Google Drive as an image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code can save an image to a sheet but I can't seem to figure out how to save it to Google Drive.
Here is a Google sheet you can copy: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AkJqpwmq0-GTveneyuQugPL900LpTS2MDpQjHz_p5lk/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function testchartbuild() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
       .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
       .addRange(sheet.getRange('A1:A12'))
       .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
       .build();
  
  // create an image from that EmbeddedChart
  sheet.insertImage(chart.getBlob(),6,1);  // this works
  
  // the file created is only 4 bytes long
  var newFile = createGoogleDriveFile(chart.getBlob());
}


function createGoogleDriveFile(image) {
  var newFile;
  
  newFile = DriveApp.createFile('test.png',image,'image/png');//Create a new file in the root folder
  
  return newFile;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your requirements:

- You want to save the chart to the Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, please modify the script of the function `createGoogleDriveFile`.

  - At the method of `createFile(blob)`, the argument is `blob`.
  - When you want to give the filename, please use `setName()`.
  - In this case, the mimeType has already been given to the blob.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

##### From:

```
newFile = DriveApp.createFile('test.png',image,'image/png');
```

##### To:

```
newFile = DriveApp.createFile(image.setName('test.png'));
```

#### References:

- [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)
- [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setnamename)